# Integracion Mercado Pago Notificaciones IPN

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago, mercadolibre

estoy realizando la integración de la api de Mercado Pago, tratando de configurar las notificaciones IPN , pero estoy experimentando dificultades para obtener los parámetros de la URL : `https://www.yoursite.com/notifications?topic=payment&id=123456789` que figura en la documentación ('topic' y 'id'). La validacion de URL la realizo correctamente en Mercado Pago, las solicitudes devuelen HTTP 200, pero no puedo extraer los parametros para poder realizar las consultas. Estoy utilizando Laravel y la configuracion de la ruta es :

`Route::post('/notifications', 'OrdenController@notifications')->name('notifications.mp');`

Lo que resulta es que la ruta donde envía MP ese tipo POST y la que indican a la que envían para extraer los parametros de tipo GET.  Es media confusa la documentacion.

Agradecería ayuda ya que estoy hace varias horas con este problemas.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo los obtengo con el siguiente metodo

```
public function notifications(Request $request){
        $datos = $request->all();
        if ( ! isset($datos["id"], $datos["topic"]) || ! ctype_digit($datos["id"])) {
            abort(404);
        }

        dd($datos);
     }
```

Comment: Intente de esa manera, veo por consola que envian las notificaciones de MP, pero no las puedo tomar, debe ser a lo mejor porque estoy trabajando con ngrok, tal vez, me tiene desconcertado.

Comment: Proba definiendo la ruta como GET: `Route::get('/notifications', 'OrdenController@notifications')->name('notifications.mp');`
Te consulto, como sabes que te envian las notificaciones si no podes levantar los valores?